# Where does a local variable get stored so that it's accessible from an asyc delegate?

Tags: c#, silverlight, delegates

At least I think what I'm referring to is a delegate. Here's my scenario

```
bool allow_login;

StationDC.Load(query, p =>
{
    if (p.Entities.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Category == "Site Status").Value == "Offline") allow_login = false;
    else allow_login = true;

}, true);
```

I still only barely understand what's actually going on here, but from what I do know the delegate I'm passing to `StationDC.Load` runs asynchronously, even if on the same thread. I'm confused though that I can access the boolean `allow_login` since I always thought delegates were more like a separate method, so should be in a different scope. Anyone have some insight as to what's going on under the hood here? How is my boolean persisting to still be around when my delegate is called?

Comment: @KirkWoll ooo Closures. I would say it's technically not a duplicate, if only because I had never heard of closures before today

Comment: still a duplicate.  Your question will act as a nice signpost for future googlers. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll Indeed! And that also answers my question. I guess my Google-fu wasn't up to this one